# Showing there is exactly one limit cycle for system in unit cirlce

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system defined by below equations:
$$\dot{x}=x+y-a^2x(x^2+y^2)$$
$$\dot{y}=-x+y-a^2y(x^2+y^2), \quad a>1$$

I'm asked to show there is only $1$ limit cycle in unit circle.

I think using Poincare-Bendixon implies there is a limit cycle but I have difficulty in showing that there is no equilibrium point in unit circle. I have no idea for showing there is only $1$ such a limit cycle. I think using polar coordinates may help but I don't know how to use it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Translate the dynamic to polar coordinates, $r\dot r=x\dot x+y\dot y$, $r^2\dot\theta=x\dot y-\dot xy$, then the answer becomes rather obvious in this case.